# Certificate error when using tech.gusavila92.websocketclient.WebSocketClient

Tags: java, android-studio, ssl, websocket

I am creating an Android App which I want to connect to my server running secure websockets (wss). My code to connect is as below:

```
private void createWebSocketClient() {
    URI uri;

    try {
        // Connect to local host
        uri = new URI("wss://mysocketsdomain:8080/ws");
    }

    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.d("Connection", "I am not even connecting");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    webSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
        @Override
        public void onOpen() {
            Log.i("WebSocket", "Session is starting");
            webSocketClient.send("Hello World!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextReceived(String s) {
            Log.i("WebSocket", "Message received");
            final String message = s;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        //TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.mainText);
                        //textView.setText(message);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onBinaryReceived(byte[] data) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPingReceived(byte[] data) {
        }


        @Override
        public void onPongReceived(byte[] data) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onException(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        @Override
        public void onCloseReceived() {
            Log.i("WebSocket", "Closed ");
            System.out.println("onCloseReceived");
        }
    };
    webSocketClient.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    webSocketClient.setReadTimeout(60000);
    webSocketClient.enableAutomaticReconnection(5000);
    webSocketClient.connect();
}
```

I am getting the error below:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

The connection works fine if I visit the web front end from a browser and I can see that the certificate is valid from the padlock symbol. Also, the frontend web app that I developed using Svelte in JavaScript works fine.

Can anyone advise what I need to do? I am reading a lot of confusing information online. Some things suggest that I need to create a trusted certificate store in the Android app. Another thing that I saw suggested it is a problem with the server certificate chain. I set the server to use the certificate file containing the chain, but the error still happens. I am not sure if it would be the server when it works for the JavaScript app and the web front end.

Answer (score 0):

try upgrade WeSocketClient library:

```
    implementation 'tech.gusavila92:java-android-websocket-client:1.2.0'
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember what I did to resolve this as it was nine months ago.